# Is there a limit for simultaneous transactions in MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, transactions, mariadb, asterisk, mariadb-10.3

There is Centos 7 server with Asterisk PBX 11.25.3 and mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.18-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64).

***extensions.conf:***

```
[from-main-asterisk]
exten => _9XXXXXXXXXXXX,1,MYSQL(Connect connid localhost root rootpasswd mydatabase)
exten => _9XXXXXXXXXXXX,n,GotoIf($["${connid}" = ""]?error,1)
exten => _9XXXXXXXXXXXX,n(select_sim),MYSQL(Query RESULTID ${connid} set autocommit=0)
exten => _9XXXXXXXXXXXX,n,MYSQL(Query RESULTID ${connid} START TRANSACTION)
exten => _9XXXXXXXXXXXX,n,MYSQL(Query RESULTID ${connid} SELECT sim_name FROM  sim_stat  where status = 'FREE'  order by rand() limit 1 ) 
exten => _9XXXXXXXXXXXX,n(sqlresult),MYSQL(Fetch fetchid ${RESULTID} SIM_NAME)
exten => _9XXXXXXXXXXXX,n,MYSQL(Clear ${RESULTID})
exten => _9XXXXXXXXXXXX,n,MYSQL(Query RESULTID ${connid} UPDATE sim_stat set status = "BUSY" where sim_name = "${SIM_NAME}") 
exten => _9XXXXXXXXXXXX,n,MYSQL(Query RESULTID ${connid} COMMIT)
exten => _9XXXXXXXXXXXX,n,Dial(SIP/gsm-${SIM_NAME}#${EXTEN:1},,g)
exten => _9XXXXXXXXXXXX,n,Hangup

exten => h,1,MYSQL(Query RESULTID ${connid} UPDATE sim_stat set status = "FREE"  where sim_name = "${SIM_NAME}")
exten => h,n,MYSQL(Query RESULTID ${connid} COMMIT)
exten => h,n,MYSQL(Disconnect ${connid})

exten => error,1,NoOp(Database connection error!)
exten => error,n,Hangup
```

***sip.conf:***

```
[from-main-asterisk]
type=friend
host=x.x.x.x
qualify=yes
qualifyfreq=60
canreinvite=no
disallow=all
allow=alaw
context=from-main-asterisk
```

When there are more than 15-20 simultaneous  calls goes from trunk i got message:

```
WARNING[2239][C-00000389] app_mysql.c: aMYSQL_query: mysql_query failed. Error: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
```

Is there a limit for simultaneous transactions in MariaDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use func_odbc, it deals with connections correctly
2. Order by rand() do scan whole table ALWAYS
3. If your table type myisam, any scan of table lock whole table.

Answer (score 0):

The number of transactions is limited to about 96K.  See https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-limitations/

`INDEX(status, sim_name)` (in that order) may speed up the lengthy query in your transaction.

Or, you might be able to avoid the table scan required by `ORDER BY rand()` by using one of the techniques here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/random

Another approach involves redesigning your application to grab, say, 10 random sim_names, mark them as being taken by your process, exit the transaction.  Then process them and finally release them in other transaction(s).

This approach of mark and release *not* being part of the transaction containing the action -- this is especially useful when the action takes a long time.

Grabbing 10 is just as fast as grabbing 1; hence that gives you speed.